# Move a particular sprite to a target position on touch in unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just started unity. I have 4 Images(sprites) aligned in a grid. Now i want to move an image to a target position as soon as I touch the image. How can i do that? 
I wrote the following code for move:

```
void Update () {
        float step=speed*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,target.position,step);
    }
```

I just don't know to move that particular sprite on which I touch.
Thanks

Comment: Attach the script to ALL sprites, and write your code in OnMouseDown() function, then when touch is detected, only the sprite who get touched get this function hooked.

Answer (score 0):

From http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/420808/how-to-get-position-of-touch-on-touch-screen.html

```
fingerPos =  Input.GetTouch(0).position;
Vector3 pos = fingerPos;
pos.z = transform.position.z;

// simplified check
if (transform.position == Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos))
{
    // move towards the target as you want
}
```

Notice that i kept it brief with that if, but, of course, you should check if the touch position is withing the boundaries of your object.

Comment: transform.position == ... is very fragile, as the vector equals are vunerable to floating point errors, eg. 1e-7 might be 0!

Comment: Actually I would check individually position.x and position.y plus their boundaries, but if there's a smarter version for doing so, I will take note :)